# The groups() method in regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am learning about regex in Python and I have problems understanding the function `groups()`.

```
>>> m = re.match("([abc])+", "abc")
```

Here I have defined the class [abc], which as I know, means any of the characters a to c. It's defined inside a group and the + sign means we want at least one of such groups. So I execute the following line and the result is understandable:

```
>>> m.group()
'abc'
>>> m.group(0)
'abc'
```

I get why this happens. The index of the main group is 0 and 'abc' matches the class we have defined. So far so good, but I don't get why the following lines get executed the way they do:

```
>>> m.group(1)
'c'
>>> m.groups()
('c',)
```

What is group(1), I have only defined one group here and why the groups function has only the character 'c' in it? Isn't it supposed to return a tuple containing all the groups? I'd suppose it would at least contain 'abc'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For `re` details consult [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group). In your case:

`group(0)` stands for all matched string, hence `abc`, that is 3 groups `a`, `b` and `c`

`group(i)` stands for i'th group, and citing documentation

> If a group matches multiple times, only the last match is accessible

hence `group(1)` stands for last match, `c`

Your `+` is interpreted as group repetation, if you want repeat `[abc]` inside group, move `+` into parentheses:

```
>>> re.match("([abc])", "abc").groups()
('a',)
>>> re.match("([abc]+)", "abc").groups()
('abc',)
```

Comment: If that's the case, why in this example the groups() function stores all the groups in a tuple:

`>>> p = re.compile('(a(b)c)d')`

`>>> m = p.match('abcd')`


`>>> m.group(2,1,2)`

`('b', 'abc', 'b')`

Comment: That example creates two different groups, which is different from one group matching multiple times with `+` or `*` repetition.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group):

> If a group matches multiple times, only the last match is accessible:

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(..)+", "a1b2c3")  # Matches 3 times.
>>> m.group(1)                        # Returns only the last match.
'c3'
```

Your group can only ever match one character, so `c` is the last match.

You mention that you'd expect to at least see `'abc'` - if you want your group to match multiple characters, put the `+` inside the group:

```
>>> m = re.match("([abc]+)", "abc")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most specified regexp, by groups you can see the protocol, filename I forgot the file-ext.

```
["](?P<protocol>http(?P<secure>s)?://)(?P<fqdn>[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?P<subdomain>(.)[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*)[/](?P<filename>([a-zA-Z.])*)["]
```

I the response removed because I was.

[image]

Comment: this answer is highly confusing and hard to understand

Comment: Im trying to use groups such of this way in the first lexical analysis you will be able to get more than one item, for example: this <protocol> is the name of protocol it could be http or https... the <fqdn> returns you hostname....

Comment: ah... I see. Now I understand better